# Notify users when the browser is minimized

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I am using AngularJS & SPring. I need to find a way to notify the users even when the user has minimized the application browser window OR IS there any other better option to notify the users based on a batch job.

Comment: why you want to notify users? which is the problem about minimizing a browser?

Comment: just chech you window sizes with timer, and if `width` is too small for you - notify

Comment: Is your goal to notify the user *that* the browser has been minimized?  Or to notify about something else, *while* the browser is minimized?

Comment: My objective is to notify the users even if the browser is minimized or not. If I notify in the application window then it may not work when the browser is minimized. So I thought of notifying something generic that will work anytime.

The reason behind the notification is to alert the users on a critical fallout and help them to take an action

Comment: How about a new popup window with given notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like `Browser Desktop Notification`.

I just found this **[LINK](http://subashselvaraj.com/2015/09/26/browser-desktop-notification-in-angularjs/)** and maybe this could help you.

```
angular.module('app', ['notifyme']).  controller('appcontroller', function($scope, NotifyMe) {
                $scope.nofity = function(){
                  var title = "I'm from Angular ?";
                  var body = 'This is a simple demo for the notification API Angular Service';
                  NotifyMe.launch(title, {
                      body: body,
                      onclick:function(){
                          console.log("On Click Triggered");
                      },
                      onerror:function(){
                          console.log("On Error Triggered");
                      },
                      onclose:function(){
                          console.log("On Close Triggered");
                      }
                  });
                };
            });
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sesubash/pw9b7c5r/3/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=pw9b7c5r) from the link: